# How to generate HTML file with Webpack by using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I found a [Vanilla-Starter repository](https://github.com/iran-react-community/Vanilla-Starter) That can generate HTML, CSS, JS file without importing any additional library.

Also, I read a lot about `Webpack` configurations and I found [`HTML-Webpack-Plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). But this plugin just generate HTML file based on `.html` file extensions.

I need to generate `.html` file based on `JavaScript` function like below:

```
import styles from './styles/styles.pcss';

export default () => `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Vanilla Starter</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="${styles.goodbye__block}">GoodBye</div>
        </body>
    </html>
`;
```

I searched a lot, but I didn't find a plugin or a way to configure my Webpack to generate an HTML file based on a `JavaScript` function.

*I need to configure my webpack to make several HTML files with using several same name JavaScript function in separated `.js` files.*

**How I can do it?**

Comment: follow the hello world from the webpack docs. problem solved.

Comment: Dear @GottZ, I wanna `Webpack` generate `.html` file for me by using a `template string` operator ES6 function. Just like I know, `Webpack` doesn't support it without using plugins, Isn't it?

Comment: yeah. probably a good idea to throw babel into the pipe